# Execute commands and print their output

Tags: ruby

Is there a way in ruby to execute a command line utility and have its output displayed in real time, something like `myrubyscript rspec`, where `myrubyscript` runs `rspec` and immediately prints output as it receives it from `rspec`?

Currently, if I invoke `rspec` with backticks or `system`, I don't see the rspec output immediately. Rather, it prints at the end.

Preferably, I want the solution to have block form, so that I run code before and after I exec the passed argument.

Comment: Not clear what you mean.

Comment: I provided another clarification.

Comment: Does it make sense to you now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Open3.popen3`.

```
require "open3"
Open3.popen3...
```